# How to change what a button does?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, actionevent

I am currently creating a game in Java using Swing. I have a button, and once it does one thing, I want it's action to change. I have tried if statements, if-else statements, while loops, and various other things, and I can't get it to work. Anyone know how to do something like this?

Comment: Everyone knows how to do something like this. You need to provide a bit more info (and probably code) so we can help you out...

Comment: Change the `ActionListener` as required...

Answer (score 4):

Create a class level attribute along the lines of:

```
boolean buttonHasFiredOnce = false;
```

In the action performed method, put code like:

```
if (!buttonHasFiredOnce) { 
  doFirstMethod();
  buttonHasFiredOnce = true;
} else {
  doSecondMethod();
}
```

Comment: If you cannot get it to work from that tip: post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt.  It should only require about 20 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest replacing the `ActionListener`

```
public static void changeAction(JButton button, ActionListener al) {
    for (ActionListener listener: button.getActionListeners()) {
        button.removeActionListener(listener);
    }
    button.addActionListener(al);
}
```

then when you want the action to change...

```
changeAction(button, new ActionListener() {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         //Insert Action Code
     }
});
```